# Libgdx Delta time stutter?

Tags: libgdx, movement

Alright, so I want my guy to move, I simply use this code.

```
velocity.y = speed;
```

Same goes for velocity.x
Thing is, the lower the framerate the slower he moves.

But, if I add delta time, the player will sometimes, randomly, jitter back. Now I've traced the problem to be the delta time, but I don't know why. This is a small output of my delta time.

```
0.017027862
0.01713779
0.015907489
0.017954277
0.015993927
0.016019527
0.017010393
0.017026054
0.016008984
0.01701702
```

So it doesn't really vary that much per frame, still the jittering keeps happening.

Any possible solutions?

Answer (score 5):

Delta time should not be used to calculate velocity, but position.

When you set velocity.y to speed, you are saying

```
"My character will move <speed> pixels per second in the y axis".
```

Later, when you update the actor's position you will calculate the y position by

```
character.position.y += velocity.y * deltaTime;
```

An easy way to think about this is distance = velocity * time